# How may I prevent the redundant blank lines before each prompt in BAT output to console?

Tags: windows-7, cmd.exe

How can I prevent the redundant blank lines before each prompt in a batch output to console?

[image: pic1]

Note: this is not the the similar question relating to redirected output.

Answer (score 0):

If you execute the BAT and pipe it through "findstr .", it should delete the blank lines (except for the last one):

```
 command.bat | findstr .
```

Comment: Unfortunately that will delete all other blank lines too.

Comment: @ChrisJJ Since the CMD processor handles command output as strings, there's no way to eliminate blank lines between commands without also eliminating the blank lines within their output - unless you want to write something like this in on *every* line of your batch file. Since you're on Windows 7, you may want to consider switching to PowerShell. It tends to handle things like this a bit more sensibly.

Comment: Thanks. I agree PowerShell handles some things more sensibly, but I find in insane in others.